# Alphabetical Scrolling in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium

I am attempting to create the Alphabetical Scroll Bar for iOS (like in iOS Contacts) using Titanium and Javascript. I have adapted some code I found [here](http://developer.http://appcelerator.com/question/49141/alphabetical-scroll-bar)

I am trying to adapt it so when a user selects a particular row, it passes the "clientname" to a new window. The code and/or most likely how I attempted to adapt it has two problems. The first row directly after the "header" row (A,B,C...) when selected does nothing, the other rows after the first do direct the user to the new window but does not pass the "clientname". Could someone please show me the code that will make this work? I am using OS 10.7.5, Titanium Studio Build: jenkins-titanium-rcp-release-788 (origin/release) Date: 20 February 2013, 12:04:51. Here is my code:
**NOTE: The code below is working code after problems were fixed**

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
win.barColor='#336699';
win.title='Alphabetical List';
win.backgroundImage='images/background.png';

var db = (function() {
var api   = {};
    api.all_item_names = function() {
        var conn = Ti.Database.install('mydb].sqlite','clients');
        var results = [];
        var resultSet = conn.execute('select * from clients order by clientname asc');
        while ( resultSet.isValidRow()) {
            results.push({
            clientname:  resultSet.fieldByName('clientname'),
        });
        resultSet.next();
    }
    resultSet.close();
    return results;
};
return api;
}());

var tvrow;
var curheader   = 'A';
var list    = [];
var index   = [];
var data   = [];
var isAndroid   = (Titanium.Platform.name == 'android');

list = ( db.all_item_names() );

for ( var ipos=0; ipos<list.length;ipos++){
    if( list[ipos].clientname[0] != curheader){
        curheader = list[ipos].clientname[0];

        tvrow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
            height:    40,
            path:'clientdetail.js' ,
            client: list[ipos],
            header:    curheader 
            });
        index.push({title:curheader, index:ipos});
    } else {
        tvrow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
            height:40,
            path:'clientdetail.js' ,
            client: list[ipos]});
        }   

var title= Titanium.UI.createLabel({ 
    left:    5, 
    top:     2, 
    height:  40, 
    color:   '#000', 
    font: {fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 'normal', fontFamily: (isAndroid?'sans-serif':'Helvetica Neue')}, 
    text:    list[ipos].clientname });
    tvrow.add(title);
    data.push(tvrow);
}

var tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:            data,
    index:           index,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    separatorStyle:  Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,
    top:             1,
    width:           '99%'
});

tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        if (e.rowData.path)
        {
            var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
                url:e.row.path,
                title:e.row.clientname
            });

        var client = e.row.client;
        win.client = client.clientname;
        Ti.UI.currentTab.open(win);
    }
});

win.add(tableView);
```

Comment: You need to ensure, that the tableview rows itself are also in alphabetical order.

Comment: Thank you Mr. VVoo. I still have a problem that the first row beneath every header does not go to the new window. All other rows below the first row will open the new window and pass the variable as desired. Here is a sketch that I hope will illustrate and explain my problem better. Any help that anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated. The sketch:        [Screenshot](http://davidnevels.com/screen.jpg)

Comment: maybe because the rows in your first if part have no path attribute?

Comment: Thank you Mr. VVoo and Mital Bhalia on developer.appcelerator. The code above has been edited showing the working code in the hope that someone else will benefit from it.